# Make a payment with Stripe

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, stripe-payments

I've been following this documentation of setting a Stripe payment element to collect card information: https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-element/migration?locale=en-GB

In my page I have created the container in which the payment element will mount into:

```
<form id="payment-form" onsubmit="event.preventDefault();">
    <div id="payment-element"></div>

    <div id="submit-container" class="d-none row mt-3 px-2">
        <button id="submit-btn" type="submit" class="submit disabled">Submit</button>
    </div>

    <div id="error-message"></div>
</form>
```

In my `JavaScript` I have the following:

```
var stripe;
var paymentElement;

$(document).ready(function () {
    showSpinner();
    initializeStripe();
    const form = document.getElementById('payment-form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', async (event) => confirm('@Model.ApplicationId'));
});

async function confirm(id) {
    showSpinner('Processing');
    debugger;
    const { clientSecret: clientSecret } = await makeAjaxCall('/payment/create-intent/' + id);
    const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
        paymentElement,
        clientSecret,
        redirect: "if_required"
    });

    if (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

function initializeStripe() {
    stripe = Stripe('@stripeOptions.Value.PublishableKey');

    const elements = stripe.elements({
        mode: 'payment',
        currency: 'gbp',
        amount: @Model.Amount
    });

    paymentElement = elements.create('payment');
    paymentElement.mount('#payment-element');

    paymentElement.on('ready', function (event) {
        hideSpinner();
        var cardImages = document.getElementById('card-images');
        var submitContainer = document.getElementById('submit-container');
        cardImages.classList.remove("d-none");
        submitContainer.classList.remove("d-none");
    });

    paymentElement.on('change', function (event) {
        var button = document.getElementById('submit-btn');
        if (event.complete) {
            button.classList.remove("disabled");
        } else {
            button.classList.add("disabled");
        }
    });
}
```

As you can see, when the `form` is submitted, I call an endpoint which I've created to create the intent and then use the `ClientSecret` to confirm the stripe payment. B

Below is essentially what the `create-intent` endpoint does:

```
StripeConfiguration.ApiKey = stripeOptions.Value.Secret;
var _paymentIntentService = new PaymentIntentService();
var intentOptions = new PaymentIntentCreateOptions
{
    Amount = parameters.Amount * 100, // 2000
    Currency = "gbp",
    PaymentMethodTypes = new List<string> { @"card" }
};

try
{
    var intent = await _paymentIntentService.CreateAsync(intentOptions);
    return intent.ClientSecret;
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    return null;
}
```

However, when `stripe.confirmPayment()` is called, despite providing the correct parameters according to the documentation, the payment fails and I get an error with the following code:

```
payment_intent_unexpected_state
```

Does anyone know what I may be doing wrong here? It's driving me insane!

**Update:**
Just had a look at the Stripe dashboard and noticed this error:

```
You cannot confirm this PaymentIntent because it's missing a payment method. You can either update the PaymentIntent with a payment method and then confirm it again, or confirm it again directly with a payment method.
```

The documentation doesn't mention anything about creating a payment method so I'm rather confused now

Answer (score 0):

The call to confirm the PaymentIntent could somehow lacking the payment elements. Your code seems to have it already (strange!) but you can put breakpoint or debug log around this part:

```
const { error } = await stripe.confirmPayment({
    paymentElement,
    clientSecret,
    redirect: "if_required"
});
```

Did `paymentElement` have a value here? Did it stop in this line? How `error` looks like? Also look at your Request Log on Stripe Dashboard and find the confirmation call, see whether it is made from your frontend. A common pitfall is your server calls confirm somewhere else where it didn't have a PaymentMethod.

To clarify, your code looks correct in the first glance, and it's the [Collect payment details before creating an intent](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/accept-a-payment-deferred?platform=web&type=payment) flow.